# Where is the option to switch desktop environments at login in Ubuntu Studio with Cinnamon also installed?

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I have Xfce-based Ubuntu Studio 18.10. I installed Cinnamon by running

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

Now, how do I switch between xfce and cinnamon at log-in?

Where is that option? I don't see the option the way it appears in Ubuntu.

Comment: @N0rbert I just edited both the title & body. I hope I didn't ruin things.

Comment: @DKBose Looks better :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no rule that all distributions must have exactly the same way to show log-in options.

For example, both Lubuntu 18.04 and Xubuntu 18.04 have that option in their panels. In the image below, I have the panel on top, and clicking on the appropriate icon shows me my log-in options:

[image: Log-in options for Lubuntu 18.04 and Xubuntu 18.04]

Lubuntu 18.10 (which has LXQt as its desktop environment), looks like this:

[image: Lubuntu 18.10]

Whereas Kubuntu 19.04 has the option in the lower left corner:

[image: Kubuntu 19.04]

If you still don't see any such icon to click on, please edit your question to post the output of `ls /usr/share/xsessions`.